# Silverlight 5: Set ConstructorArgument on a IMarkupExtension class

Tags: xaml, markup-extensions, silverlight-5.0

I would like to have a MarkupExtension that can be initiated with just one value, much like `Binding`:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding MyPath}"/>` instead of `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyPath}">`

In WPF this is done with the [`ConstructorArgumentAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.constructorargumentattribute.aspx), but this doesn't exist in Silverlight.
I checked for attributes on the `Path` property of `Binding` but have'nt found any attributes applied to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reading into the documentation that I've found so far, I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: @Jeff So how come the SL team did it!? I won't fall asleep until I get to know it :)
I know it's impossible out the box, they would've surely done this att. I'm looking for a workaround, or at least an explanation of how they're doing it.

Comment: I suspect they have some private/internal code that allows them to achieve this on known types. However, we only get `IMarkupExtension` to play with and that on its own doesn't seem to support it. As they write the parser, they can easily look for known extensions like `Binding` and give special case handling.

Comment: But I think it's too many of them (`Binding`, `TemplateBinding`, `StaticResource`, `RelativeSource` and many others), it doesn't really make sense that they made a list of known types and addressed the parameters.
But I would love to hear about any idea how they did it if you manage to trap it down with [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I realize that it's not yet implemented.

So if you think this feature is compelling, please go ahead and vote for this feature [here](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1821667-please-add-constructorargumentattribute-to-the-sl-).

Hope this answer to be updated as soon as I have any piece of news (hope this to happen asap...).